# How to setup a group policy to set a logon script on every user in Active Directory using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I know how to set group policy to add a logon script to every user using GUI but I wanted to know how can this be done using Powershell commands(or maybe with python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only real way to **set** a GPO setting via powershell requires that you know the registry key you're changing (all GPO settings resolve to registry entries), but be aware that settings done like this won't show up with the nice descriptions in the group policy gui tools:

```
Get-GPO -Name 'Logon Scripts' | Set-GPRegistryValue -Context User -Key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\path\to\key' -Value 'Foo.bat'
```

Generally, the better way to do what you want is to set the AD User's `ScriptPath` property instead:

```
Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADUser -ScriptPath 'Foo.bat'
```